# How to dynamically render an element on clicking a button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

"I want to render an animation on clicking a button. but it won't render on clicking it.You can get an animation from https://lottiefiles.com. or i have shared it below just copy paste it ". Also the animation should be rendered over the previous view.

Code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button,Text,Platform, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      flag:false,
      x: ''
    } 
    this.fun = this.fun.bind(this); 
  }

fun(){  
    return React.createElement(LottieView, {
  style: {
    flex: 1
  }, 
  source: require('./animation.json'),
  autoPlay:true,  
  loop: true,      
}); 
  } 
  render(){ 
    this.x=this.fun()
    return(  
      <View style={{flex: 1}}> 
        <Button            
            title="Reject"  
            color="#FF0000" 
            onPress ={()=>this.setState({flag:true})}  
          />  
      {this.flag?<View style={{flex: 1}}>{this.x}</View>:<Text>hello</Text>}  
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is animation json file

```
{"v":"4.10.1","fr":48,"ip":0,"op":48,"w":56,"h":56,"nm":"录入声纹 tick","ddd":0,"assets":[],"layers":[{"ddd":0,"ind":1,"ty":4,"nm":"对勾","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[28,28,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0.988,5.188,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[66.824,66.824,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"o":[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],"v":[[-13.398,3.94],[-1.702,13.989],[20.038,-8.302]],"c":false},"ix":2},"nm":"路径 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[1,1,1,1],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":6,"ix":5},"lc":1,"lj":1,"ml":4,"nm":"描边 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"变换"}],"nm":"形状 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.446],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.078],"y":[0.582]},"n":["0p446_1_0p078_0p582"],"t":19,"s":[0],"e":[86]},{"t":31}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.667],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.333],"y":[0]},"n":["0p667_1_0p333_0"],"t":21,"s":[0],"e":[60]},{"i":{"x":[0.667],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.333],"y":[0]},"n":["0p667_1_0p333_0"],"t":26,"s":[60],"e":[0]},{"t":31}],"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"修剪路径 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false}],"ip":12,"op":468,"st":-12,"bm":0},{"ddd":0,"ind":3,"ty":4,"nm":"形状图层 1","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[28,28,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[-0.121,0.371,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.667,0.667,0.667],"y":[1,1,1]},"o":{"x":[0.706,0.706,0.333],"y":[0.004,0.004,0]},"n":["0p667_1_0p706_0p004","0p667_1_0p706_0p004","0p667_1_0p333_0"],"t":0,"s":[0,0,100],"e":[111.445,111.445,100]},{"i":{"x":[0.105,0.105,0.667],"y":[0.984,0.984,1]},"o":{"x":[0.333,0.333,0.333],"y":[0,0,0]},"n":["0p105_0p984_0p333_0","0p105_0p984_0p333_0","0p667_1_0p333_0"],"t":12,"s":[111.445,111.445,100],"e":[100,100,100]},{"t":19}],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"d":1,"ty":"el","s":{"a":0,"k":[48.469,48.469],"ix":2},"p":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":3},"nm":"椭圆路径 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Ellipse","hd":false},{"ty":"fl","c":{"a":0,"k":[0.462745098039,0.443137254902,0.737254901961,1],"ix":4},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":5},"r":1,"nm":"填充 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[-0.121,0.371],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"变换"}],"nm":"椭圆 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":144,"st":0,"bm":0}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution like this.
use a state(say x) along with the component in {x && component} and initially set state to false, and on button click set the state x to true your component will be rendered

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
 state1:false
}
}

render(){
return(
<Button onPress={()=>this.setState({state1:true})/>
{ this.state.state1 && <your component that you want to render> }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter the variable check:

```
render() { 
  this.x = this.fun();
  return(  
    <View style={{flex: 1}}> 
      <Button            
        title="Reject"  
        color="#FF0000" 
        onPress={() => this.setState({flag:true})}  
      />  
      {this.state.flag ?
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>{this.x}</View> :
        <Text>hello</Text>
      }  
   </View>
  );
}
```

There is no 'this.flag', so you needed to alter it to this.state.flag - then the code should work. I would say change onPress to onClick but I understand onPress is react native - do you need to use TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight, TouchableNativeFeedback instead of Button?

You will also need to add some code in to account for multiple presses. For example, what if someone presses the button again during the animation, you don't want it starting again.